# Keyboard shortcut to rename a variable?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, when you change the name of a variable, a small red square appears underneath it and when you hover over it, a bigger yellow box appears, and when you click on that an option appears to automatically rename all instances of that variable to the new name. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this? It would be much faster than trying to hover over the tiny red box for half an hour... (if it matters I'm using the C# code editor)

EDIT: I am aware of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+**<kbd>.</kbd>** but is there one where you don't have to press enter afterwards? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F2  displays the **Rename** dialog box, which allows renaming all references for an identifier.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can rename variables of this easy ways: Right click -> Rename or Ctrl+R-> Ctrl+R

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I was looking for a keyboard-only way rather than using the mouse :)